# Is it possible to copy a CMS theme design to transfer to wordpress

Tags: wordpress, content-management-system, kentico

I tried researching it but do not find a direct answer I am trying to move a kentico cms website to wordpress but would like to know if it is possible to copy the kentico theme design to then place it within my new wordpress website?

Thank you all feedback and suggestions welcomed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not without manually changing some parts around and adding the WordPress related functions, no.

While you'll probably be able to copy your CSS file, you will have to do the basic WP theme work, e.g. adding the informational comment to your style.css, make sure your header and footer call `wp_head()` and `wp_footer()`, add the functions to work with [the loop](https://codex.wordpress.org/The_Loop) to output content etc.

You can find lots of detailed [documentation on creating themes](https://codex.wordpress.org/Theme_Development) in the codex.